# If then statement with an or clause in vbs/hta

Tags: vbscript, wmi, hta

I have a section of VBScript code that queries `Win32_Service` based on a certain name condition. Now we have half environment migrated to the new name, so I need to modify the script to run the code block on either condition. I have searched the web, but cannot find any examples. I am pasting the two code blocks in. I need to query for either RGL or Reed as the start to a service name and return the results. Any ideas are appreciated.

```
 ' Initialize Objects.
  Set g_objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.")
  Set g_colServices = g_objWMIService.InstancesOf("Win32_Service")

  If c_Debug Then h_divStatus.style.display = "block"

   For Each g_objService In g_colServices 
    'Status "Checking service..."
    If c_Reedonly Then
      If LCase(Left(g_objService.DisplayName, 4)) = LCase("RGL ") Then
'      'If c_Debug Then
'        'WScript.Echo "Name: " & g_objService.Name & vbCrLf & _ 
'        '    "Display Name: " & g_objService.DisplayName & vbCrLf & _ 
'        '    " Description: " & g_objService.Description & vbCrLf & _ 
'        '    " Path Name: " & g_objService.PathName & vbCrLf & _ 
'        '    " Start Mode: " & g_objService.StartMode & vbCrLf & _ 
'        '    " State: " & g_objService.State & vbCrLf 
'        'AddRowLinePartial(g_objService.Name)
        AddRowLinePartial "h_tblServices", g_objService.DisplayName, g_objService.Name, g_objService.State, g_objService.StartMode
      End If
    Else
      AddRowLinePartial "h_tblServices", g_objService.DisplayName, g_objService.Name, g_objService.State, g_objService.StartMode
    End if
    Next
    Else
    For Each g_objService In g_colServices 
    'Status "Checking service..."
    If c_Reedonly Then
      If LCase(Left(g_objService.DisplayName, 4)) = LCase("Reed") Then
'      'If c_Debug Then
'        'WScript.Echo "Name: " & g_objService.Name & vbCrLf & _ 
'        '    "Display Name: " & g_objService.DisplayName & vbCrLf & _ 
'        '    " Description: " & g_objService.Description & vbCrLf & _ 
'        '    " Path Name: " & g_objService.PathName & vbCrLf & _ 
'        '    " Start Mode: " & g_objService.StartMode & vbCrLf & _ 
'        '    " State: " & g_objService.State & vbCrLf 
'        'AddRowLinePartial(g_objService.Name)
        AddRowLinePartial "h_tblServices", g_objService.DisplayName, g_objService.Name, g_objService.State, g_objService.StartMode
      End If
    Else
      AddRowLinePartial "h_tblServices", g_objService.DisplayName, g_objService.Name, g_objService.State, g_objService.StartMode
    End if
  Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Or keyword in your If statement.  You can do both at once.

```
' Initialize Objects.
Set g_objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.")
Set g_colServices = g_objWMIService.InstancesOf("Win32_Service")

If c_Debug Then h_divStatus.style.display = "block"

For Each g_objService In g_colServices 
    'Status "Checking service..."
    If c_Reedonly Then
        If LCase(Left(g_objService.DisplayName, 4)) = LCase("RGL ") _
                Or LCase(Left(g_objService.DisplayName, 4)) = LCase("Reed") Then
'   'If c_Debug Then
'   'WScript.Echo "Name: " & g_objService.Name & vbCrLf & _ 
'   '   "Display Name: " & g_objService.DisplayName & vbCrLf & _ 
'   '   " Description: " & g_objService.Description & vbCrLf & _ 
'   '   " Path Name: " & g_objService.PathName & vbCrLf & _ 
'   '   " Start Mode: " & g_objService.StartMode & vbCrLf & _ 
'   '   " State: " & g_objService.State & vbCrLf 
'   'AddRowLinePartial(g_objService.Name)
            AddRowLinePartial "h_tblServices", g_objService.DisplayName, g_objService.Name, g_objService.State, g_objService.StartMode
        End If
    Else
        AddRowLinePartial "h_tblServices", g_objService.DisplayName, g_objService.Name, g_objService.State, g_objService.StartMode
    End If
Next
```